# Core Data Stack not saving or reverting to default?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am making a quiz app. I already have a Core Data Stack that is working. However I want to have another Stack to store results and have tried to set it up in same way as first.

It operates across two View Controllers - UnitSelectionController (where 2nd Core Stack should be updating number of attempts, number correct etc.) from the QuizController which is logging attempts, correct etc.

I can see that the logging is working with attempts, correct increasing as the should be. The data is being transferred to the Stack Attribute variables successfully and I the saveContext is firing but changing view controller to load next quiz seems to be losing the data that should have been saved and I'm back where I started with default values.

```
class CoreDataStackResults {
    
    static let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Results")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()
    
    static var context: NSManagedObjectContext { return persistentContainer.viewContext }
    
    class func saveContext2 () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        
       guard context.hasChanges else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saveContext2 peformed")
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Then in UnitSelection Controller within viewWillAppear I have:

```
    let fetchResultsRequest: NSFetchRequest<Progression> = NSFetchRequest<Progression>(entityName: "Progression")
    do{
        let progression = try CoreDataStackResults.context.fetch(fetchResultsRequest)
        self.progression = progression

    } catch {}
    
    
    loadResults()
    labelResults()
```

loadResults and labelResults :

```
   func loadResults(){
        print("Results being loaded?")
        let progression = Progression(context: CoreDataStackResults.context)
        unitOneCount = progression.unitOneAttempts
        print("unitOneCount = \(unitOneCount)")
        unitTwoCount = progression.unitTwoAttempts
        unitThreeCount = progression.unitThreeAttempts
        unitFourCount = progression.unitFourAttempts
        unitFiveCount = progression.unitFiveAttempts
        unitSixCount = progression.unitSixAttempts
        unitSevenCount = progression.unitSevenAttempts
        unitEightCount = progression.unitEightAttempts
        unitNineCount = progression.unitNineAttempts
        unitOneCountCorrect = progression.unitOneCorrect
        unitTwoCountCorrect = progression.unitTwoCorrect
        unitThreeCountCorrect = progression.unitThreeCorrect
        unitFourCountCorrect = progression.unitFourCorrect
        unitFiveCountCorrect = progression.unitFiveCorrect
        unitSixCountCorrect = progression.unitSixCorrect
        unitSevenCountCorrect = progression.unitSevenCorrect
        unitEightCountCorrect = progression.unitEightCorrect
        unitNineCountCorrect = progression.unitNineCorrect
    }
    
    func labelResults(){
        print("Results being labelled?")
        UnitOneCountLabel.text = "Attempts:  \(unitOneCount)"
        UnitTwoCountLabel.text = "Attempts:  \(unitTwoCount)"
        UnitThreeCountLabel.text = "Attempts:  \(unitThreeCount)"
        UnitFourCountLabel.text = "Attempts:  \(unitFourCount)"
        UnitFiveCountLabel.text = "Attempts:  \(unitFiveCount)"
        UnitSixCountLabel.text = "Attempts:  \(unitSixCount)"
        UnitSevenCountLabel.text = "Attempts:  \(unitSevenCount)"
        UnitEightCountLabel.text = "Attempts:  \(unitEightCount)"
        UnitNineCountLabel.text = "Attempts:  \(unitNineCount)"
        
    }
```

If I change the default value in the Data Stack then the Count variables and Labels change accordingly.

Moving onto QuizController. Within viewWillAppear:

```
 let fetchResultsRequest: NSFetchRequest<Progression> = NSFetchRequest<Progression>(entityName: "Progression")
        do{
            let progression = try CoreDataStackResults.context.fetch(fetchResultsRequest)
            self.progression = progression
        } catch {}
        
        let progression = Progression(context: CoreDataStackResults.context)
        
        unitOneCount = progression.unitOneAttempts
        print("progression.unitOneAttempts = \(progression.unitOneAttempts)")
        unitTwoCount = progression.unitTwoAttempts
        unitThreeCount = progression.unitThreeAttempts
        unitFourCount = progression.unitFourAttempts
        unitFiveCount = progression.unitFiveAttempts
        unitSixCount = progression.unitSixAttempts
        unitSevenCount = progression.unitSevenAttempts
        unitEightCount = progression.unitEightAttempts
        unitNineCount = progression.unitNineAttempts
        unitOneCountCorrect = progression.unitOneCorrect
        unitTwoCountCorrect = progression.unitTwoCorrect
        unitThreeCountCorrect = progression.unitThreeCorrect
        unitFourCountCorrect = progression.unitFourCorrect
        unitFiveCountCorrect = progression.unitFiveCorrect
        unitSixCountCorrect = progression.unitSixCorrect
        unitSevenCountCorrect = progression.unitSevenCorrect
        unitEightCountCorrect = progression.unitEightCorrect
        unitNineCountCorrect = progression.unitNineCorrect
```

Then as questions are answered, the newQuestionCode is used to determine which Unit question came from and starts to count attempts and correct answers for each Unit.

```
func allocateQuestion(){
        questionUnit = Int16(Int(newQuestionCode.prefix(1)) ?? 0)
        print ("Question Code = \(Int(newQuestionCode.prefix(1)) ?? 0)")
        
        if (questionUnit == 1) {
            unitOneCount += 1 }
        
        if (questionUnit == 2){
            unitTwoCount += 1 }
        
        if (questionUnit == 3){
            unitThreeCount += 1 }
        
        if (questionUnit == 4){
            unitFourCount += 1 }
        
        if (questionUnit == 5){
            unitFiveCount += 1 }
        
        if (questionUnit == 6){
            unitSixCount += 1 }
        
        if (questionUnit == 7){
            unitSevenCount += 1 }
        
        if (questionUnit == 8){
            unitEightCount += 1 }
        
        if (questionUnit == 9){
            unitNineCount += 1 }
        
        print("Unit One Count = \(unitOneCount)")
        print("Unit Two Count = \(unitTwoCount)")
        print("Unit Three Count = \(unitThreeCount)")
        print("Unit Four Count = \(unitFourCount)")
        print("Unit Five Count = \(unitFiveCount)")
        print("Unit Six Count = \(unitSixCount)")
        print("Unit Seven Count = \(unitSevenCount)")
        print("Unit Eight Count = \(unitEightCount)")
        print("Unit Nine Count = \(unitNineCount)")
        

  if(allQuestions.list.prefix(prefixNumber).count >= 0){
   let progression = Progression(context: CoreDataStackResults.context)
      
        progression.unitOneAttempts = unitOneCount
      print("progression.unitOneAttempts = \(progression.unitOneAttempts)")
        progression.unitTwoAttempts = unitTwoCount
        progression.unitThreeAttempts = unitThreeCount
        progression.unitFourAttempts = unitFourCount
        progression.unitFiveAttempts = unitFiveCount
        progression.unitSixAttempts = unitSixCount
        progression.unitSevenAttempts = unitSevenCount
        progression.unitEightAttempts = unitEightCount
        progression.unitNineAttempts = unitNineCount
            
      CoreDataStackResults.saveContext2()
        
        }
    }




func allocateQuestionCorrect(){
    questionUnitCorrect = Int16(Int(newQuestionCode.prefix(1)) ?? 0)
    print ("Correct Question Code = \(Int(newQuestionCode.prefix(1)) ?? 0)")

if (questionUnitCorrect == 1) {
    unitOneCountCorrect += 1 }

if (questionUnitCorrect == 2){
    unitTwoCountCorrect += 1 }

if (questionUnitCorrect == 3){
    unitThreeCountCorrect += 1 }

if (questionUnitCorrect == 4){
    unitFourCountCorrect += 1 }

if (questionUnitCorrect == 5){
    unitFiveCountCorrect += 1 }

if (questionUnitCorrect == 6){
    unitSixCountCorrect += 1 }

if (questionUnitCorrect == 7){
    unitSevenCountCorrect += 1 }

if (questionUnitCorrect == 8){
    unitEightCountCorrect += 1 }

if (questionUnitCorrect == 9){
    unitNineCountCorrect += 1 }

print("Unit One Correct Count = \(unitOneCountCorrect)")
print("Unit Two Correct Count = \(unitTwoCountCorrect)")
print("Unit Three Correct Count = \(unitThreeCountCorrect)")
print("Unit Four Correct Count = \(unitFourCountCorrect)")
print("Unit Five Correct Count = \(unitFiveCountCorrect)")
print("Unit Six Correct Count = \(unitSixCountCorrect)")
print("Unit Seven Correct Count = \(unitSevenCountCorrect)")
print("Unit Eight Correct Count = \(unitEightCountCorrect)")
print("Unit Nine Correct Count = \(unitNineCountCorrect)")
```

let progression = Progression(context: CoreDataStackResults.context)

```
progression.unitOneCorrect = unitOneCountCorrect
print("progression.unitOneCorrect = \(progression.unitOneCorrect)")
progression.unitTwoCorrect = unitTwoCountCorrect
progression.unitThreeCorrect = unitThreeCountCorrect
progression.unitFourCorrect = unitFourCountCorrect
progression.unitFiveCorrect = unitFiveCountCorrect
progression.unitSixCorrect = unitSixCountCorrect
progression.unitSevenCorrect = unitSevenCountCorrect
progression.unitEightCorrect = unitEightCountCorrect
progression.unitNineCorrect = unitNineCountCorrect

CoreDataStackResults.saveContext2()

}
```

So, I see the unitCount and unitCountCorrect going up when appropriate and I see "saveContext2 peformed" message but when quiz is over and it moves back to UnitSelectionController none of the values have changed and on loading next quiz it is back to original default values (zero) and starts counting fresh.

Comment: What do you mean with two stacks?

Comment: I have another Stack called Flags which stores other data needed for my quiz. originally I tried adding another Entity to this stack. When it wasn't working I thought I'd make a second Stack called Results with just the Entity "Progression". Has the advantage in theory (I think) of only updating the data needed for "Progression" without forcing all my other data to be checked all the time. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think you should try again to add that entity to your original stack, what you have now is a really complicated solution for what seems like a simple problem.

Comment: I returned the entity to the original stack and it has made no difference .... but I will leave it that way. Thank you very much for taking the time to look at my problem and make a comment. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Key was (eventually) to write the correct code to read my stored data from the Stack.This was placed in viewDidLoad so only runs when App is opening.

```
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<QuizResults> = NSFetchRequest<QuizResults>(entityName: "QuizResults")
    do{
        let results = try QuizResultsStack.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.results = results
    } catch {}
    for result in results{
        unitOneCount = result.unitOneAttempts
        unitTwoCount = result.unitTwoAttempts
        unitThreeCount = result.unitThreeAttempts
        unitFourCount = result.unitFourAttempts
        unitFiveCount = result.unitFiveAttempts
        unitSixCount = result.unitSixAttempts
        unitSevenCount = result.unitSevenAttempts
        unitEightCount = result.unitEightAttempts
        unitNineCount = result.unitNineAttempts
        unitOneCountCorrect = result.unitOneCorrect
        unitTwoCountCorrect = result.unitTwoCorrect
        unitThreeCountCorrect = result.unitThreeCorrect
        unitFourCountCorrect = result.unitFourCorrect
        unitFiveCountCorrect = result.unitFiveCorrect
        unitSixCountCorrect = result.unitSixCorrect
        unitSevenCountCorrect = result.unitSevenCorrect
        unitEightCountCorrect = result.unitEightCorrect
        unitNineCountCorrect = result.unitNineCorrect
    }
```

Along the way, I decided it was 'easier' to transfer the values between my two ViewControllers embedded in my override functions:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    
    if segue.destination is QuizController{
let gvc = segue.destination as? QuizController
gvc?.unitOneCount = unitOneCount
            print(" from UnitSelection Controller to QuizController    gvc?.unitOneCount = \(unitOneCount))")
            gvc?.unitTwoCount = unitTwoCount
            gvc?.unitThreeCount = unitThreeCount
            gvc?.unitFourCount = unitFourCount
            gvc?.unitFiveCount = unitFiveCount
            gvc?.unitSixCount = unitSixCount
            gvc?.unitSevenCount = unitSevenCount
            gvc?.unitEightCount = unitEightCount
            gvc?.unitNineCount = unitNineCount
            gvc?.unitOneCountCorrect = unitOneCountCorrect
            gvc?.unitTwoCountCorrect = unitTwoCountCorrect
            gvc?.unitThreeCountCorrect = unitThreeCountCorrect
            gvc?.unitFourCountCorrect = unitFourCountCorrect
            gvc?.unitFiveCountCorrect = unitFiveCountCorrect
            gvc?.unitSixCountCorrect = unitSixCountCorrect
            gvc?.unitSevenCountCorrect = unitSevenCountCorrect
            gvc?.unitEightCountCorrect = unitEightCountCorrect
            gvc?.unitNineCountCorrect = unitNineCountCorrect
}
```

And, coming the other way was when I also updated the Core Data Stack:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToUnitSelection" {
        print("Override segue unwindToUnitSelection")
        let usvc = segue.destination as? UnitSelectionController
        
        
        usvc?.unitOneCount = unitOneCount
        print(" usvc?.unitOneCount = \(unitOneCount))")
        usvc?.unitTwoCount = unitTwoCount
        usvc?.unitThreeCount = unitThreeCount
        usvc?.unitFourCount = unitFourCount
        usvc?.unitFiveCount = unitFiveCount
        usvc?.unitSixCount = unitSixCount
        usvc?.unitSevenCount = unitSevenCount
        usvc?.unitEightCount = unitEightCount
        usvc?.unitNineCount = unitNineCount
        usvc?.unitOneCountCorrect = unitOneCountCorrect
        usvc?.unitTwoCountCorrect = unitTwoCountCorrect
        usvc?.unitThreeCountCorrect = unitThreeCountCorrect
        usvc?.unitFourCountCorrect = unitFourCountCorrect
        usvc?.unitFiveCountCorrect = unitFiveCountCorrect
        usvc?.unitSixCountCorrect = unitSixCountCorrect
        usvc?.unitSevenCountCorrect = unitSevenCountCorrect
        usvc?.unitEightCountCorrect = unitEightCountCorrect
        usvc?.unitNineCountCorrect = unitNineCountCorrect
        
        
            print("should be updating QuizResultsStack")
        

        
        
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "QuizResults", in: QuizResultsStack.context)
        
        let quizzy = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: QuizResultsStack.context)
        
        quizzy.setValue(unitOneCount, forKey: "unitOneAttempts")
        quizzy.setValue(unitTwoCount, forKey: "unitTwoAttempts")
        quizzy.setValue(unitThreeCount, forKey: "unitThreeAttempts")
        quizzy.setValue(unitFourCount, forKey: "unitFourAttempts")
        quizzy.setValue(unitFiveCount, forKey: "unitFiveAttempts")
        quizzy.setValue(unitSixCount, forKey: "unitSixAttempts")
        quizzy.setValue(unitSevenCount, forKey: "unitSevenAttempts")
        quizzy.setValue(unitEightCount, forKey: "unitEightAttempts")
        quizzy.setValue(unitNineCount, forKey: "unitNineAttempts")
        quizzy.setValue(unitOneCountCorrect, forKey: "unitOneCorrect")
        quizzy.setValue(unitTwoCountCorrect, forKey: "unitTwoCorrect")
        quizzy.setValue(unitThreeCountCorrect, forKey: "unitThreeCorrect")
        quizzy.setValue(unitFourCountCorrect, forKey: "unitFourCorrect")
        quizzy.setValue(unitFiveCountCorrect, forKey: "unitFiveCorrect")
        quizzy.setValue(unitSixCountCorrect, forKey: "unitSixCorrect")
        quizzy.setValue(unitSevenCountCorrect, forKey: "unitSevenCorrect")
        quizzy.setValue(unitEightCountCorrect, forKey: "unitEightCorrect")
        quizzy.setValue(unitNineCountCorrect, forKey: "unitNineCorrect")
        

        
        do {
            try QuizResultsStack.context.save()
        }
        catch {
            // Handle Error
        }
        
        
       
    } }
```